# stringWithFormat : 5 parameters?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

why are we using here 5 parameters for `stringWithFormat` :

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"LatLongFormat", @"LatLongFormat"), fabs(self.coordinate.latitude), latString, fabs(self.coordinate.longitude), lonString];
```

i guess the second param is the *value* for the third param, the *key*, but what about the first parameter?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand well your question but you can use as many parameters as you want for stringWithformat method. It will build a string according to these parameters.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I %@ %d nice %@",@"build",1,@"string"]
```

mystring will contain "I build 1 nice string".

Comment: ok thanks, i did not understand that the `%d` and others parameters where in the localizable.strings file, my mistake, thanks for the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is the format used for formatting the remaining parameters.